# Displaying properly p:blockUI on whole page with p:layout

Tags: css, jsf, layout, primefaces

I have following layout:

```
<h:body>
    <p:outputPanel layout="block" id="page" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
        <h:panelGroup layout="block">

            <p:layout fullPage="true">
                <p:layoutUnit id="top" position="north" size="60">
                    ...
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit id="left" position="west" size="145" header="Menu" resizable="true" collapsible="true">
                    ...
                </p:layoutUnit>

                <p:layoutUnit id="center" position="center">
                    ...
                </p:layoutUnit>

            </p:layout>
        </h:panelGroup>
    </p:outputPanel>
</h:body>
```

In center layout unit I defined some blockUI component:

```
<p:blockUI block=":page" trigger="searchButton">
```

I would like to block whole page, but div with block layer is under layoutUnit divs. So I can see this blockUI layer in spaces between layout units only and I want to see it on top as first layer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding to the primefaces user's guide as the following: -

> #### Forms in Full Page Layout
>
> When working with forms and full page layout, avoid using a form that contains layoutunits as generated dom may not be the same. **So following is invalid**.

```
<p:layout fullPage="true">
<h:form>
    <p:layoutUnit position="west" size="100">
        <h:outputText value="Left Pane" />
    </p:layoutUnit>
    <p:layoutUnit position="center">
        <h:outputText value="Right Pane" />
    </p:layoutUnit>
</h:form>
```

> ***A layout unit must have it’s own form instead***, also avoid trying to update layout units because of same reason, update it’s content instead.

Then we can not manage the p:layout or p:layoutUnit, since they are not under the form.

Answer (score 2):

Add display:block; style to the outputPanel like this:

```
<p:outputPanel layout="block" id="page" style="display:block;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not block the `p:layout` instead of wrapping it in a `div` and blocking the wrapper?

```
<p:layout id="page" ...

<p:blockUI block=":page" ...
```

Comment: I tried with p:layout also and blockUI didn't show up at all.

Answer (score 0):

The question should be accepted as the best answer.
Infact it works as posted. Layout block or style display:block are not required,
it is already the default for p:outputPanel. But the width and height are important.

So i ended up using:

```
<p:outputPanel id="page" style="width:100%;height:100%;">
```